# Как спрасить цену из выпадающей ссылки?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Есть задание: спарсить цену из конкретных ссылок, одна из которых -  https://pechisamara.ru/otopitelnye-pechi.html#images-4.
Вроде бы, тег обозначен верно, класс тоже, однако выводит пустой результат. В чём проблема?

```
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('div', class_='fancybox-caption__body')
print(price.text)
```

Comment: Я что-то не нашел что именно надо спарсить, но попробуй сделать вот так: clear_price = [i.text for i in price]

Comment: 'В чём проблема?' одним словом javascript. Анализируйте исходный код страницы в котором прекрасно видно отсутствие 'div' class='fancybox-caption__body'.

Comment: да это какой то просмоторщик в исходном коде нет

Comment: я этот класс достал через панель разработчика, там цена была обёрнута в этот div с таким классом, а суп его не находит, выводит пустой словарь

Comment: "через панель разработчика" хотите как в браузере используйте селенимум. requests.get скачивает исходный код страницы который может не совпадать с кодом "через панель разработчика" в браузере. Под ваш код надо анализировать исходный код страницы, а не код "через панель разработчика" в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pechisamara.ru/otopitelnye-pechi.html#images-4'
indx = int(url.rsplit('-', 1)[1])
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
lst = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('p', class_="price")]
print(lst[indx-1])
```